Proof that a solution exists using Intermediate Value Theorem $f(x) + n = ne^x$
Suppose $f$ is a function that is continuous on $[-1, 1]$ and that $m \leq f(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$. Prove that there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that the equation $f(x) + n = ne^x$ has a solution in the interval $(-1, 1)$. This was from a test based on the Limits chapter of Calculus: Early Transcendentals 6 Ed.
My initial idea was to use the Intermediate Value Theorem by letting $g(x) = f(x) + n - ne^x$ and proving that there exists some $c \in [-1, 1]$ such that $g(x)$ changes sign in that interval. I know $m +n -ne^x \leq g(x) \leq M + n -ne^x$ but I can't work out how to make the proof general.

Call $g_n(x)=ne^x-n$. Then $g_n(-1)=n(e^{-1}-1)$ and  $g_n(1)=n(e-1)$ .
Pick $n$ large enough such that $n(e^{-1}-1)<m$. Then $g_n(-1)<m\le f(-1)$.
Next pick $n$ even larger, if needed, such that $n(e-1)>M$. Then $g_n(1)>M\ge f(1)$.
Conclusion: for such large $n$ you have
$$
f(-1)>g_n(-1);\qquad f(1)<g_n(1)
$$
By IVT, there is some $x\in (-1,1)$ such that $f(x)=g_n(x)$, as desired.
